# Waiting list in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a model for a training that has the fields below:

```py
class Training(models.Model):
    registered = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    waiting_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    max_registered = models.models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    starting_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    finishing_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Training")
```

My problem is to implement functionality for max registered participants to a training. When registered.count() == max_registered it should put users on the "waiting_list" instead of "registered". Any suggestions on how I should implement this? Is this something done in backend or frontend? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible to do this in the view, but I'd approach this differently by adjusting the model. After all, the User can be part of `registered` or `waiting_list` and not from both.

Answer (score 0):

You can override save method which means you can custom what is done when an object is saved:

```py
class Training(models.Model):
    registered = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='registered')
    waiting_list = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='waiting')
    max_registered = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    starting_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    finishing_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Training"
        
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.registered.count() > self.max_registered:
            # append waiting list
            self.waiting_list.add(self.registered.last())
            # drop last registered
            self.registered.remove(self.registered.last())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```